# Seeking Guidance: Email Validation Error Handling for Specific Scenarios for field in account object

Tags: email, validation-rule, standard-objects, regular-expressions, admin

I'm facing an email validation challenge for my project. I want to throw an error if any of the following scenarios are met:

1. The email has **numbers at the end**, like 'email1@email.com123'.
2. The email **contains the '&' character**, like 'email2&email@email.com'.
3. The email **includes the '/' character**, like 'email3/email@email.com'.

Could anyone kindly guide me on how to implement this validation in my code?
Your assistance would be greatly appreciated!
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done in a validation rule with the following formula:

```
CONTAINS(My_Field__c, '/') || CONTAINS(My_Field__c, '&') || ISNUMBER(RIGHT(My_Field__c, 1))
```

- The first two conditions check whether your field contains a `/` or a `&`.
- The last condition gets the last character (using `RIGHT`) and then checks if it is a number using `ISNUMBER`

Comment: Thank you very much Sir

Answer (score 0):

```
// Define a method that takes an email as a parameter and returns a boolean value
public static Boolean validateEmail(String email) {
        // Declare a variable to store the regular expression pattern for a valid email
        String pattern = '^[a-zA-Z0-9._%+-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9.-]+\\.[a-zA-Z]{2,4}$';
        // Create a Pattern object using the pattern
        Pattern p = Pattern.compile(pattern);
        // Create a Matcher object using the email and the pattern
        Matcher m = p.matcher(email);
        // Return true if the email matches the pattern, false otherwise
        return m.matches();
}

// Define a method that takes a list of emails as a parameter and throws an exception if any of them is invalid
public static void checkEmails(List<String> emails) {
        // Loop through the emails
        for (String email : emails) {
                // Call the validateEmail method and store the result
                Boolean isValid = validateEmail(email);
                // If the result is false, throw an exception with the invalid email
                if (!isValid) {
                        throw new EmailException('Invalid email: ' + email);
                }
        }
}

// Define a custom exception class for invalid emails
public class EmailException extends Exception {}
```

This code will create two methods: one to validate a single email using a regular expression, and another to check a list of emails and throw an exception if any of them is invalid.

The regular expression will reject any email that has **numbers at the end**, contains the **'&' character**, or includes the **'/' character**, as per your scenario.